# Infopath 2010 How to get the total of fields with a Time Data Type in a repeating table

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

Please help... I am noob to Infopath coding and I am having a hard time with finishing a project. I have setup a repeating table where it should count the time spent for each activity. Below is the screenshot

[image: Repeating Table Screenshot]

I want to be able to get the total time for the column "Activity Time" and place it on the Footer of the repeating table. I already tried Googling for some answers but can't find one for a Time Data Type.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infopath cannot add time values into a total like that. You need to convert the time values into numbers, then sum the numbers and convert the result back into a time value.

Step by step instructions are on the InfoPath blog from Microsoft here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/21/calculating-elapsed-time-without-code.aspx